# Python: check mail with smtplib and handle errors

Tags: python, dns, smtp

I need to check emails programmatically. I'm using this code:

```
    resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    resolver.timeout = 3
    resolver.lifetime = 3
    mx_records = resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
    for mxRecord in mx_records:
        mxRecord = str(mxRecord.exchange)
        host = socket.gethostname()
        server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=30)
        server.set_debuglevel(0)
        addressToVerify = var0
        server.connect(mxRecord)
        server.helo(host)
        server.mail('me@domain.com')
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
        server.quit()
        res_email = 'Not Found'
        if code == 250:
            result = 'Success'
        else:
            print "doesn't exist"
```

I'm receiving an error when I run this code:

```
Connection unexpectedly closed
Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 10054] 
[Errno 10061]
```

I have tried to change values of timeout, but it didn't help. I then tried to specify the port in `smtplib.SMTP()`, but specified `587` and that didn't resolve the issue either.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You want to send to, or receive from, a known server for which you are a legitimate user?

Comment: @BillBell I need only to check email

Comment: SMTP is the sending protocol. You need either poplib or imaplib in Python, depending on whether your email is POP3 or some variant of IMAP.

Comment: @Bill Bell; I have a similar issue; any quick and easy way of determining what the email is ?

Comment: @bobox: Is your email server POP3? If so, I can write an answer because I have access to one. Otherwise, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @bobox: I've dropped an answer in.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the code to interrogate a POP3 server from the Python help file. Here it is in ever-so-slightly modified form.

```
import poplib, getpass

pop = poplib.POP3('***********', port=110)
pop.user('**********')
pop.pass_('*********')
print (pop.stat())
print (pop.list()[1])
```

You have only to copy various constants such as the port number from your mail client.

What this script produces as output might surprise you, depending on the settings in your mail client. Here's what I just got.

(43, 1104784)
[b'1 15848', b'2 7889', b'3 7938', b'4 3705', b'5 28933', b'6 35479', b'7 12793', b'8 7094', b'9 10045', b'10 12793', b'11 17194', b'12 312802', b'13 12688', b'14 18431', b'15 24454', b'16 17769', b'17 16223', b'18 14975', b'19 11951', b'20 13373', b'21 34949', b'22 23647', b'23 14958', b'24 22449', b'25 5068', b'26 14920', b'27 8611', b'28 10982', b'29 14311', b'30 7477', b'31 3852', b'32 8497', b'33 4086', b'34 7240', b'35 69458', b'36 19430', b'37 110263', b'38 2434', b'39 12043', b'40 5306', b'41 10288', b'42 17164', b'43 74974']

But I know that no messages remain on the server that I haven't received in my mail client. The answer to this minor puzzle is that my email client leaves messages on the server for a fortnight, or until I delete them, by default, presumably as a safeguard against loss in case of some kind of computer failure.

This implies that it would be insufficient to simply use the above output as a check for new messages. It would be necessary to record dates from headers from received messages for up to a fortnight for comparison with those on the server.